# C# reflection avoid propertie

Tags: c#, reflection

Im using reflection to acess a class tha represents a table in DB.However,reflection read all properties of that class,and im wondering if there're some atributte in c# we can use to avoid read that propertie.

i.e:

```
[AvoidThisPropertie]
public string Identity
{
get;
set;
}
```

Comment: Define "avoid read". Do you mean that you don't want methods like `GetProperties` to find the property at all? Or do you want to avoid reading the property value after discovering it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
PropertyInfo [] properties = MyType.GetProperties(
    BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public);

IList<PropertyInfo> crawlableProperties = properties.Where(
    p => p.GetCustomAttributes(
        typeof(AvoidThisProperty), true)
        .Count() == 0);
```

You'd also have to create the `AvoidThisProperty`

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property)]
public class AvoidThisPropertyAttribute : Attribute
{
   // Doesn't need a body
}
```

You still have access to all the properties, but the LINQ statement would generate a list of the *desired* properties.

Answer (score 1):

If you could avoid full accessibility, reflection would have no sense